# Magento Custom Options Automatically

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9, observer-pattern

This extension I made works fine when I save the product. It simply adds the custom options.

Here is config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Custom_Options>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Custom_Options>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <custom_options>
            <class>Custom_Options_Model</class>
        </custom_options>
    </models>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before><!-- observe the event -->
            <observers>
                <custom_options>
                    <class>custom_options/observer</class>
                    <method>autoMetaDescription</method>
                </custom_options>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

Observer.php

```
<?php 
class Custom_Options_Model_Observer {
public function autoMetaDescription($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    //check that we haven't made the option already
    $options = $product->hasCustomOptions();
   if( $product->getData('has_options') && ($product->getTypeID() == 'simple')){

} else
 {
 $option6 = array(
        'title' => 'Hardware Finish',
        'type' => 'drop_down',
        'is_require' => 1,
        'sort_order' => 4,
        'is_delete' => '',
        'previous_type' => '',
        'previous_group' => '',
        'price' => '0.00',
        'price_type' => 'fixed',
        'sku' => '',
        'values' => array(
            array(
                'is_delete' => 0,
                'title' => 'Black Nickel',
                'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'price' => 0,
                'option_type_id' => -1,
            )

              );


           //don't use it like this because it has no effect
     //$product->setProductOptions($options);
    $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

   $product->getOptionInstance()->addOption($option6);

  //don't forget to state that the product has custom options
    $product->setHasOptions(true);
    //$product->save();
}
  }
 }
```

Basically there are some products which doesn't have custom options but it always adds options to them too. I think there's a way to overcome this problem is to use action called when creating a product.
[As In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct3U4.png)

Please tell me which action or controller is called when this button is pressed, or any other method to overcome this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question

> Please tell me which action or controller is called when this button is pressed, or any other method to overcome this problem is appreciated.

To observe the initial creation of a product you can observe the `catalog_product_new_action`.

It sounds like you're trying to prevent certain products from being manipulated by your observer.  If this is the case, I would recommend that you create an attribute that is Yes/No that enables/disables the the AutoMetaDescription function.  Just check the value of the attribute before manipulating the product.

Comment: If that worked for you then go ahead and accept my answer!